# How GC know which memory is to deallocate?

Tags: c++, garbage-collection

I was curious about Garbage Collector in C++. I can understand they can control memory allocation by using their allocation method. Like Boehm GC

```
#include "gc.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i;

  GC_INIT();    /* Optional on Linux/X86; see below.  */
  for (i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
   {
     int **p = (int **) GC_MALLOC(sizeof(int *));
     int *q = (int *) GC_MALLOC_ATOMIC(sizeof(int));
     assert(*p == 0);
     *p = (int *) GC_REALLOC(q, 2 * sizeof(int));
     if (i % 100000 == 0)
       printf("Heap size = %d\n", GC_get_heap_size());
   }
  return 0;
}
```

but i don't understand how GC will know the variable is no longer in use ? and it should be deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection is all about pointers. If you can reach an allocated block of memory by following a chain of pointers then that block of memory is still potentially in use and should not be deallocated. The difficulty in C++ is knowing what is a pointer and what isn't. Once C++ is compiled it's hard to tell the difference between a pointer and an integer

Boehm is what is called a conservative garbage collection, which essentially means it assumes everything is a pointer. This means that sometimes it doesn't free memory that it could. Perhaps an integer variable has a value which is the same as the address of an alocated block of memory.

Even so it's still possible to fool Boehm, in a language like C++ its possible to manipulate pointers (using pointer arithmetic for instance) and so Boehm will end up freeing memory that is still in use.